# Prove that $f$ is strictly convex iff $A$ is positive definite

Tags: convex-analysis, quadratic-forms, positive-definite

I would like to have a help with this question.

> Let $$f(X) = \frac{1}{2}X^TAX + b^TX$$ with $A=A^T$. Prove that $f(X)$ is strictly convex if and only if $A$ is positive definite.

Regards!

Comment: By definition, you need to show that $\langle f(X)u, u\rangle$ is convex for any vector $u$. Compute the [Hessian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Functions_of_n_variables).

Comment: Horrible notation!!! Some vectors are uppercase, others are lowercase. Be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is actually on minute 29:02 in this [YouTube lecture](https://youtu.be/XzW-B1CJ_ao).

If $A$ is symmetric and PD, then what you say is true. You got that $f(X)$ is differentiable with respect to $X$ hence it suffices to prove the second order condition, namely,

$$\nabla^2 f(X) = A \succ  0$$

Hence $f(X)$ is stricly convex.

Comment: quite right! thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The hessian of the function becomes $$\nabla^2f(X)={1\over 2}(A+A^T)=A$$now what does strict convexity imply here and impose on $\nabla^2f(X)$?

Comment: Your matrix is not even symmetric, let alone [positive definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definiteness_of_a_matrix).

Comment: Symmetry is not assumed in the problem, but thanks for reminding me that.

Comment: assumed A as symmetric, sorry for not mentioning that

Comment: The Hessian matrix of $f$ is A. So if we suppose that A is positive definite, then the eigen values of A are positive strictly. The Hessian matrix is positive definite , so due to second order sufficient condition for strict convexity characterization, the function is strictly convex.

Comment: That's quite right. The same is true for the converse too!